# Handlebars show list of items in array

Tags: arrays, handlebars.js

I have the following document which I need to pass values into a template using handlebars. I have managed to display all the values except for those of `reps` and `kilos` which I can't seem to access.
How could I write my template code to reach those values? I want to print them out in pairs, so `reps[0`] with `kilos[0]` and so on.

```
{
  "personId": "Mario",
  "date": "7-10-2014",
  "workout": {
    "exercise": "Military Press",
    "musclegroup": "Shoulders",
    "sets": [
      {
        "reps": [
          "20",
          "30"
        ],
        "kilos": [
          "22",
          "33"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

This is my template so far.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset = "utf-8"/>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">

  <!-- CSS Stylesheets -->
  <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./../../static/styles/main.css">


  <!-- Adding google fonts -->
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Yanone+Kaffeesatz:300|Satisfy' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

  <!-- Scripts -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <!-- Title & logo -->
    <div id="header">
      <h1><i class="fa fa-book"></i> loGym</h1>
    </div>

    <!-- Main body of page -->
    <main role=”main”>

        <div id="content">
            <h2><strong>Workout</strong></h2>

            {{#if content}}
              {{#content}}
                <p><strong>Date</strong> - {{date}}</p>
                <p><strong>Muscle Group</strong> - {{workout.musclegroup}}</p>
                <p><strong>Exercise</strong> - {{workout.exercise}}</p>
                <p><strong>Sets</strong></p>
                    <ul id="setList">
                      {{#sets}}

                      <li>Reps: {{reps}} - KG: {{kilos}}</li>
                      {{/sets}}
                    </ul>
                {{/content}}
            {{else}}
                <p>There are not documents avalable.</p>
            {{/if}}
        </div>

        <form>
          <input type="button" id="homeButton" class="buttons" value="Home Page" onclick="window.location.href='/'">
        </form>

    </main>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to utilize the {{#each}} and {{this}} statements.  Not 100% sure on the formatting you are going for, but here's a quick example.

```
{{#if content}}
          {{#content}}
            <p><strong>Date</strong> - {{date}}</p>
            <p><strong>Muscle Group</strong> - {{workout.musclegroup}}</p>
            <p><strong>Exercise</strong> - {{workout.exercise}}</p>
            <p><strong>Sets</strong></p>
                <ul id="setList">
                  {{#sets}}

                  <li>Reps: {{#each reps}}{{this}}{{/each}} - KG: {{#each kilos}}{{this}}{{/each}}</li>
                  {{/sets}}
                </ul>
            {{/content}}
        {{else}}
            <p>There are not documents avalable.</p>
        {{/if}}
```

Comment: Still doesn't output the values.

Comment: I was missing the `workout` identifier when calling `sets`. So it should be `{{#workout.sets}}` and not `{{#sets}}`. Thanks, now its working :)